# Cómo evitar cargar un dato dos veces con Ajax jQuery y PHP?

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql, ajax

Hola Gente de stackoverflow hoy tengo un problema es que estoy haciendo un chat pero hay veces que carga 2 ó 3 veces los mismos datos, el error esta en que se actualiza 3 veces en la primera funcion llamada `llenaMensajePrimeraVez` en el ajax y en el PHP `flagPrimeraVez` como puedo hacer deje de cargar los datos duplicados la primera vez Bueno espero que me ayuden

Codigo front (html, css, js):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    .mostrar_mensaje {
        height: 440px;
        padding: 12px;
        width: 96%;
        /* border-radius: 5px; */
        overflow-x: hidden;
        border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="mostrar_mensaje" id="mostrar_mensaje"></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var out, isScrolledToBottom;
    out = document.getElementById("mostrar_mensaje"); // outer container of messages

    // initial load of chat                     ////**Chat post id
    cargaMensajeChat(1,llenaMensajePrimeraVez);

    // check for chatter every second
    setInterval(function() {

        isScrolledToBottom = checkIfScrolledBottom();
        cargaMensajeChat(0,llenaMensajeSiguientesVeces);

    }, 1000);

    function checkIfScrolledBottom() {
        // allow for 1px inaccuracy by adding 1
        return out.scrollHeight - out.clientHeight <= out.scrollTop + 1;
    }

    function scrollToBottom(scrollDown) {
        if (scrollDown)
        out.scrollTop = out.scrollHeight - out.clientHeight;
    }

    //funcion carga mensajes del servidor por ajax
    function cargaMensajeChat(vFlagPrimeraVez,callback){
        var vidchat=obtenerUltimoIdChat();
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "load_chat.php",
            data: {
                flagPrimeraVez : vFlagPrimeraVez,
                idchat : vidchat
            },
            success: function(data){
                callback(data);             
            }
        })
    }
    //funcion llena div primera vez
    function llenaMensajePrimeraVez(contenido){
        $('#mostrar_mensaje').html(contenido);
    }
    //funcion llena agrega solo nuevos mensajes (append)
    function llenaMensajeSiguientesVeces(contenido){
        if($.trim(contenido)!=''){
            $('#mostrar_mensaje').append(contenido);
            out = document.getElementById("mostrar_mensaje");
            scrollToBottom(isScrolledToBottom);
        }
    }
    //recorre los div del chat, todos tienen atributo id="chat", coge el ultimo que es quien tiene el mayor id
    function obtenerUltimoIdChat(){
        return $("div[idchat]:last").attr("idchat");
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Código PHP:

```
    require("conectarbd.php");
    include ("app/data.php");

////**This file is for languages    
if (@$_COOKIE["muser"]!='') {   
    require ("languages/".userdata('language',false).".php");
} else {
    require ("languages/".$Language.".php");
}




$id = $_GET['v']; 
////** This is to know if the room exists   
    $DataPaste = mysql_query("SELECT * from paste WHERE pasteID=$id ");
if (mysql_num_rows($DataPaste) == 0)
{
            echo '<br><br><br><center><img src="'.$sitio_url.'img/500.png"></img><br>
            '.$Languages_136.'!</center>';

}else{ 
    //SO, recibe flag primera_vez que carga pagina
    $flagPrimeraVez = $_GET['flagPrimeraVez'];
    @$idchat = $_GET['idchat'];

    //SO, validando flag
    if($idchat!='' && $idchat>0){//SO, seria despues de la primera vez, entonces se carga solomensajes nuevos
        $data_chat = mysql_query("SELECT * from chat WHERE post=$id AND id>$idchat ");            
    }else{//SO, de lo contrario solo carga todos los mensajes
        $data_chat = mysql_query("SELECT * from chat WHERE post=$id ");
    }

        if (mysql_num_rows($data_chat) == 0)
        {         
            //SO, en primera vez si no hay mensajes se muestra imagen no_messages.png       
            if($flagPrimeraVez=='1'){
                    echo '<br><br><br><center><img src="'.$sitio_url.'img/no_messages.png"></img><br>
                    '.$Languages_12.'!</center>';
            }else{//SO, de lo contrario se envia mensaje en blanco
                echo '';
            }
        }else{  

            while($res=mysql_fetch_array($data_chat)){
                    $ads=$res["ads"];
                    $pads=$res["pads"];
                    $embed=$res["link"];
                    $tipo=$res["tipo"];

/////Mensaje
                        $come[0]='';
                        $come[1]=''.$Ads_Two.'';
// // // // // // // // // // // // // // Content Type------------------------->
// // // // // // chat
                         //SO, agregando idchat
                         $type[0]='<div idchat='.$res["id"].' id="chat" class="message__chat">
                                            <img class="resize--img" src="'.date_image(''.$res["userID"].'').'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal-user" data-id="'.$res["userID"].'" id="getUser">
                                        <div id="chat" class="wall_chat_body">
                                            <p class="message__text"><spam class="message__username" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal-user" data-id="'.$res["userID"].'" id="getUser">'.date_name_user(''.$res["userID"].'').'</spam><spam class="message__username_time">'.time_elapsed($res["time"]).'</spam><br>'.parseString(nl2br(bb_parse(Hashtag(''.$res["mensaje"].'')))).'</p>
                                        </div>
                                   </div>'.$come[$ads].'';
// // // // // // imagen        
                        //SO, agregando idchat
                        $type[1]='<div idchat='.$res["id"].' id="chat">
                                <div class="message__img">
                                        <img class="resize--img" src="'.date_image(''.$res["userID"].'').'" alt="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal-user" data-id="'.$res["userID"].'" id="getUser">
                                    <div class="wall_chat_body_image">
                                        <p class="message__text"><spam class="message__username" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal-user" data-id="'.$res["userID"].'" id="getUser">'.date_name_user(''.$res["userID"].'').'</spam><spam class="message__username_time">'.time_elapsed($res["time"]).'</spam></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    <div class="message__chat m--user">
                                        <div class="message__text t--user">
                                            <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal-media" data-id="'.$res["id"].'" id="getMedia">
                                            <img class="playgif" data-swap="Thumbnails?img='.upload_image($res["id"]).'&data='.$res["post"].'" src="Thumbnails?img='.upload_image($res["id"]).'&thumbs=1&data='.$res["post"].'" alt="" width="100%" height="100%">
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>';
// // // // // // audio     

                        $type[2]='<div idchat='.$res["id"].' id="chat"><div class="message__img">
                                                <img class="resize--img" src="'.date_image(''.$res["userID"].'').'" alt="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal-user" data-id="'.$res["userID"].'" id="getUser">
                                            <div class="wall_chat_body_image">
                                                <p class="message__text"><spam class="message__username" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal-user" data-id="'.$res["userID"].'" id="getUser">'.date_name_user(''.$res["userID"].'').'</spam><spam class="message__username_time">'.time_elapsed($res["time"]).'</spam></p>
                                            </div>
                                          </div>
                                <div class="message__chat m--user">
                                    <p class="message__text t--user">
                                    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal-media" data-id="'.$res["id"].'" id="getMedia">
                                    <img src="img/tool.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%">
                                    </a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>';    



////** Here are the chat messages   
                echo $type[$tipo];
////** This is the function for external links                  
                echo ''.External_links($res["link"]).''; 

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Hola, yo creería que para un chat se debe utilizar sokect.io, si es posible implementarlo.

Comment: si quieres si pero es muy sokect es mejor ajax o node.js

Comment: es con node.js, utilizas diferente puerto pra llamar a node y dejas como esta e de apache.

Comment: Hola @Shareiv, ¿por que no envías la petición con un filtro de fecha?, de manera que cuando realice la petición se tenga en cuenta la fecha del último mensaje que hay en el chat y solo obtenga los posteriores a dicha fecha.

Comment: Me puedes dar un ejemplo ya que no soy bueno con Ajax por favor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realmente lo que debes hacer es esperar a que se termine de ejecutar la función `llenaMensajePrimeraVez()` para que se comience a ejecutar la función `llenaMensajeSiguientesVeces()`, lo cual lo podrías hacer creando una variable que sirva como disparador o switche pero aplicándole un `setTimeout()` para que de tiempo de terminar la primer ejecución.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var out, isScrolledToBottom;
    var activarMasMensajes = false;
    out = document.getElementById("mostrar_mensaje"); // outer container of messages

    // initial load of chat                     ////**Chat post id
    cargaMensajeChat(1, llenaMensajePrimeraVez);

    // check for chatter every second
    setInterval(function() {
        if (activarMasMensajes) {
            isScrolledToBottom = checkIfScrolledBottom();
            cargaMensajeChat(0, llenaMensajeSiguientesVeces);
        }
    }, 1000);

    function checkIfScrolledBottom() {
        // allow for 1px inaccuracy by adding 1
        return out.scrollHeight - out.clientHeight <= out.scrollTop + 1;
    }

    function scrollToBottom(scrollDown) {
        if (scrollDown)
        out.scrollTop = out.scrollHeight - out.clientHeight;
    }

    //funcion carga mensajes del servidor por ajax
    function cargaMensajeChat(vFlagPrimeraVez,callback){
        var vidchat=obtenerUltimoIdChat();
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "load_chat.php",
            data: {
                flagPrimeraVez : vFlagPrimeraVez,
                idchat : vidchat
            },
            success: function(data){
                callback(data);             
            }
        })
    }
    //funcion llena div primera vez
    function llenaMensajePrimeraVez(contenido){
        $('#mostrar_mensaje').html(contenido);

        setTimeout(function(){
            activarMasMensajes = true;
        }, 1000);
    }
    //funcion llena agrega solo nuevos mensajes (append)
    function llenaMensajeSiguientesVeces(contenido){
        if($.trim(contenido)!=''){
            $('#mostrar_mensaje').append(contenido);
            out = document.getElementById("mostrar_mensaje");
            scrollToBottom(isScrolledToBottom);
        }
    }
    //recorre los div del chat, todos tienen atributo id="chat", coge el ultimo que es quien tiene el mayor id
    function obtenerUltimoIdChat(){
        return $("div[idchat]:last").attr("idchat");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Analizando tu código creo que el problema esta en emplear setInterval, primero haces el llamado de los últimos mensajes sin embargo en simultaneo se esta ejecutando el setInterval, por lo que la función se repitiria con el mismo ultimo id durante el tiempo que ajax tarda en llenarte esos nuevos mensajes.

Espero haberme dejado entender.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69484/discussion-between-shareiv-and-fabrizio-piminchumo).

Answer (score 3):

Que tal no se si te sirva usar una bandera global usando el localStorage Object de javascript.

crear variable: `localStorage.setItem("entroPrimeraVez", "no");`
obtener valor : `var bandera = localStorage.getItem("entroPrimeraVez");`
Eliminar variable: `localStorage.getRemove("entroPrimeraVez");`

Funciona como una variable estática, no se elimina hasta que borres Cookies o la elimines con localStorage.getRemove.

Puedes verlo en https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Espero sirva de algo la información que proporciono, Saludos.

ejemplo:

```
       if(localStorage.getItem("bandera") === null){
                alert("primera vez");
                //genera variable bandera
                localStorage.setItem("bandera","entro");

            }else{
            //la variable bandera tiene como valor entro.
            //De aqui en adelante estaria entrando al else hasta eliminar la variable
                alert("Segunda vez"+localStorage.getItem("bandera"));
            }
function elminar(){
      localStorage.removeItem("bandera")
}
```

Comment: ya lo estoy haciondo pero no funciona me puedes dar un ejemplo usando mi codigo por favor

Comment: Que tal genere un ejemplo, esa condicional puedes agregarla en cualquier parte de tu javascript si agregas el if else  luego de que cargue el documento funcionaria la bandera.

Comment: no esta igual duplica 2 veces

Comment: `$('div[idchat]').each(function() {
   var $ids = $('div[idchat=' + this.id + ']');
   if ($ids.length > 1) {
    $ids.not(':first').remove();
   }
  });`

Comment: tu sabes como meter este codigo en mi code?

Comment: Deja lo veo, solo que mañana, igual voy a replicar el código que tienes de muestra en mi local para ver mas a detalle.

Comment: ok muchas gracias amigo